# hibernate implementation with play framework 2.3x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

i am working with play framework 2.3x, I implemented hibernate with play framework but i am getting null value in session factory in controller class. Actually this sessionFactory is not getting hibernate-cfg.xml file.
please cheak

**My build.sbt is**

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2"
)
```

**My conf/Hibernate-cfg.xml is**

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password"></property>
            <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>


        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
**My Model class is**
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends Model {
    public static Finder<Integer, Customer> find = new Finder<Integer, Customer>(
            Integer.class, Customer.class
    );

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cid")
    int cid;
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    public int getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(int cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static List<Customer> findAll() {
        return find.all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your JPA configuration in the `conf/META-INF/persistance.xml`. This is the standard location for JPA and Hibernate is just an implementation of JPA. Play has a couple of additional configurations in the `conf/application.conf`. There is a nice tutorial for [Integrating Play with JPA](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA).

Another point: Do you use `@Transactional` annotation in your controller methods? If not you have to explicitly tell Play to start a Transaction with `JPA.withTransaction` manually.